# How to know which key is pressed on UIKeyboard in ios?

Tags: ipad, ios5, uikeyboard, uikeyinput

I am implementing a iPad application. In my application I need to know which key is pressed in the keyborad. Can you guys please help me is there any way to find it?

Thank you,
Sekhar.

Comment: Can you provide some more info on the view and perhaps some code?  I don't think there's enough info here for someone to help you.  What have you tried?

Comment: Actullay we have dismiss key in iPad default keyboard I need to customize that button action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vague question, but if you simply want to know what key has been tapped you need to implement a `delegate` for input control that called the keyboard.  For example if you are using a `UITextView`, then implement the `UITextViewDelegate`, wire up the control's delegate property to you class, and then implement the `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`.  When `UITextView` recognizes a change then it will call this method.  You can then watch for the characters in the "replacementText" argument.

With `UITextField` use the `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.

You can do other things with `UITextField` like change the Return button to a Done button in Interface Builder.  The implement the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method.  If it's called then run the `resignFirstResponder` on the object passed to the method.

Hope this helps.