# How to find out that keyboard down arrow key pressed, programmatically

Tags: objective-c, keyboard

I know that when down arrow key is pressed on keyboard then we can get Keyboard Hide notification but the problem is, we get Keyboard Hide notification also when we rotate the device and keyboard hides, now how to differentiate that keyboard is hiding because of key pressed not because of rotation.[image]

Comment: [This may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417976/how-to-know-which-key-is-pressed-on-uikeyboard-in-ios)

Comment: you do? im suprised you get a keyboard hide on device rotation sounds like you problem is somewhere else.

Comment: This is because I am reloading tableview on orientation change.

Comment: ahh that makes it a bit more clear, you can't really tell why the keyboard hid. you can set a BOOL before the table reload and read that in your even handler.

Answer (score 3):

In your AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
      addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) 
      name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
      return YES;
}


-(void) keyboardWillHide {
  NSLog(@"Bye");
}
```

Comment: I already did that, but as I said on orientation change also it is calling keyboardWillHide method, since I am reloading tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Following `Delegate` method of `textfield` is called automatically when we clicked on the `return or arrow button` of `keyboard`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: This method will not get called for down arrow, I guess.

Comment: sorry try with - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField method of textfield.