# IOS keyboard on hide button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to monitor the keyboard hide button on IOS and fire an event on that. I'm talking about:

[image: ipad keyboard]

I want to monitor only then the actual button is pressed by the user. I don't want the event when keyboard hides.

Comment: did you try UIKeyboardWillHideNotification?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know which key is pressed on UIKeyboard in ios?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417976/how-to-know-which-key-is-pressed-on-uikeyboard-in-ios)

Comment: No, not yet, I'll try this

Comment: Checking UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is the best way for this .

Comment: @Clement: The UIKeyboardWillHideNotification comes in when the keyboard is going to be hidden but this is the cause not the agent when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

User keyboard notification observers..

**For Swift**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillAppear"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


func keyboardWillAppear() {
    println("Keyboard appeared")
}

func keyboardWillHide() {
    println("Keyboard hidden")
}
```

**For Objective-C**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                       object:nil];
// register for keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                       object:nil];
```

Comment: This sends a notification of when the keyboard is hidden but this is not the same as the notification of when the user clicks on the "hide keyboard" button or whatever it is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notif
{
//keyboard will hide
}
```

`UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` also can be used.

If you don't have any other triggers to hide keyboard (such as tap outside or hide on return) you can ensure that the event triggered by the '*keyboard hide*' button

Answer (score 0):

For a strange reason, when the user pressed the `hide keyboard button`, the event `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` is fired.

This is the only way I found to know if the user pressed the `hide keyboard button`:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillAppear(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification.rawValue), object: nil)
```

```swift
@objc func keyboardWillAppear(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let info: [AnyHashable: Any] = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo {
        if let keyboardCGRect = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
           keyboardCGRect.height > 100 {
           // Keyboard is presented
        } else {
           // User pressed the hide button.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check below -

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (text.length != 0) {
        // Get the Ascii character
        int asciiCode = [text characterAtIndex:0];

        if (asciiCode == 10) {

            // your keyboard hide button is press

        }
    }
}
```